# Nerd font not fond in terminal profile

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, fonts, zsh

I installed **Hack Regular Nerd Font Complete** by downloading the .ttf file [here](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/blob/master/patched-fonts/Hack/Regular/complete/Hack%20Regular%20Nerd%20Font%20Complete.ttf). I opened the .ttf file directly and clicked "install", and it told me that the font was installed. However, I cannot find it in my terminal profile, and consequently my powerlevel9k works not well with those icons. How can I fix the problem?

I use Gnome-Terminal on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Did you try [the original Hack](https://sourcefoundry.org/hack/)? Is the font available in other programs, e.g. LibreOffice? In either case it doesn’t hurt to update the font cache files with `sudo fc-cache`.

Comment: I've already done `sudo fc-cache`, but still no change. The Hack Nerd Font is available in wps office.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the patched version just isn’t a monospace font anymore – if the patch added symbols that’s quite possible. Did you try the original font? I use Hack in my terminal emulator (which of yourse also only lets you choose from monospace fonts), so I can confirm it works.

Comment: There is no problem using the regular font Hack, and Hack Nerd Font Regular is surely a monospace font since I'm using it well by setting the default monospace font to Hack Nerd Font. There might be problems for the system to recognize the monospace font.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GNOME Terminal's Preferences window (as of version 3.28, shipped by Ubuntu 18.04) only offers you monospace fonts. It might need further investigation why your particular font is not believed to be monospace.

You can set any font using `dconf` (e.g. in `dconf-editor`), under `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:<profile-id>/font`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I used Tweaks to set the system default monospace font to Hack Nerd Font Regular, and it works. But when I was using `dconf-editor`, I could only modify the string value of profiles, which is very confusing to me. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I've slightly updated my answer, hope that helps.